# How to unpack generator results from ProcessPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, generator, concurrent.futures

I am trying to use `ProcessPoolExecutor` to initiate multiple instances of a class (`BT`), which initiates a method `BT.bt()`, and return results [`aList1`, `aList2`].

I have tried to package info which is required by each instance of the class into a simple iterator (`bulkInfo`). The iterator is then thrown to each instance of the class and executed. As I understand it, the results should be a generator or a list, with each result (`combiList`) in results being a list of 2 'minilists' [`aList1`, `aList2`].

However I cannot unpack the results. Or more correctly, I cannot unpack each `result in results`. Pycharm highlights warnings at `result[0]` and `result[1]` — `Class 'BT' does not define '__getitem__', so the [] operator cannot be used on its instances`.

Running the code as is gives error `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`.
The full version of the code gives error `TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object`.

**How to unpack each `result` in `results` to give me `miniList1` and `miniList2`?**

The code below is a stripped back version to outline the problem. I have tried using `yield` instead of `return combiList`. I have tried throwing `results` to `list(results)` and iterating through each result. I have tried many variations of packing the `bulkinfo` iterator as a list of lists or a list of tuples. I have tried defining `combiList` as a list and as a tuple. I have tried `list(results)` followed by `list(result)` to access each `miniList`.

```
import concurrent.futures as cf
import numpy as np

class BT:
    def __init__(self, bulkInfo):
        self.aCyc = bulkInfo(3)
        self.bt(self.aCyc)

    def bt(self, aCycle):
        aList1 = []
        aList2 = []
        someInfo = [aCycle, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff']
        [aList1.append(s) for s in someInfo]
        [aList2.append(s) for s in someInfo]
        combiList = [aList1, aList2]
        return combiList

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dummy1 = 'something'
    cycles = np.arange(10)
    bulkInfo = []
    [bulkInfo.append([dummy1, dummy1, dummy1, aCyc]) for aCyc in cycles]

    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        results = executor.map(BT, bulkInfo)

        for result in results:
            miniList1 = result[0]
            miniList2 = result[1]

        # for result in list(results):
        #     for miniList in list(result):
        #         print(miniList)
```

I am not so concerned with performance, but just trying to get the results out of the `ProcessPoolExecutor`. So I simply want output results as a list, but perhaps it is a generator (It is not clear to me here when lists are "becoming" generators, or vice versa. I just want to extract `miniList1` and `miniList2`.)

Comment: It looks like your 'result' is not a list. Can you try to print the type of each result? `print(type(result))`

Comment: results is <class generator>. cannot determine individual result, get errors as described above

Comment: a single result should be an instance of combiList, which is [aList1, aList2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple issues with your `BT` object.

First, in `__init__()`, you cannot access the element of `bulkInfo` (which is a list) with `()`, you need to use brackets. This is why you get `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`. Here's the corrected version :

```py
def __init__(self, bulkInfo):
    self.aCyc = bulkInfo[3]
    self.bt(self.aCyc)
```

Second, your init method returns a `BT` object, not a list of lists. This is what the `__init__` method does : it creates an object and returns it. So, the content of your `executor.map` is an iterable of `BT` objects. By changing `combiList` as an attribute of your object, you can access it using `result.combiList[i]`.

While we are at it, you don't have to pass `self.aCyc` as an argument of your `bt()` method : since it is an attribute, you can access it freely in the object methods.

Last, you can also directly iterate over your `executor.map` without the need for a `results` variable.

Here's the complete working code :

```py
import concurrent.futures as cf
import numpy as np

class BT:
    def __init__(self, bulkInfo):
        self.aCyc = bulkInfo[3]
        self.bt()

    def bt(self):
        aList1 = []
        aList2 = []
        someInfo = [self.aCyc, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff']
        [aList1.append(s) for s in someInfo]
        [aList2.append(s) for s in someInfo]
        self.combiList = [aList1, aList2]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dummy1 = 'something'
    cycles = np.arange(10)
    bulkInfo = []
    [bulkInfo.append([dummy1, dummy1, dummy1, aCyc]) for aCyc in cycles]

    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        for result in executor.map(BT, bulkInfo):
            print(result.combiList)
            miniList1 = result.combiList[0]
            miniList2 = result.combiList[1]
```

Which gives me the following output :

```
[[0, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff'], [0, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff']]
[[1, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff'], [1, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff']]
[[2, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff'], [2, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff']]
[[3, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff'], [3, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff']]
[[4, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff'], [4, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff']]
[[5, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff'], [5, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff']]
[[6, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff'], [6, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff']]
[[7, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff'], [7, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff']]
[[8, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff'], [8, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff']]
[[9, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff'], [9, 'bunch', 'of', 'stuff']]
```

Comment: Nicely done Kusefiru. Thx. I am inexperienced with classes and your outline has given me several excellent pointers...I am surprised PyCharm did not pick up on the bulkInfo brackets...

Comment: I don't use PyCharm, but I guess that it does not because by default function arguments are not typed (so it can't know that bulkInfo is a list).
You need to use type hints if you want to specify the type of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(self._translate, itertools.repeat(text), languages)
        rlist = []
        for res in results:
            rlist.append(res)
            # print(type(res))
        return rlist
```

you can create list and append it like here `rlist.append(res)`